# Not able to curl jenkins service from other ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have jenkins installed on one of the ec2 instances. I am able to run the below commands on the **same** ec2 and confirm that the connection is successful.

```
curl -vk 'http://<private ip>:9009/jenkins'
curl -vk 'http://localhost:9009/jenkins'
```

However, I cannot execute these commands from any other ec2 instance even though security group attached to the jenkins ec2 instance allows all kinds of inbound connections.

I get below error when I try connecting from other ec2 instances.

```
[root@ip-<private ip> ~]# curl -vk 'http://<private ip>:9009/jenkins'
* About to connect() to <private ip> port 9009 (#0)
*   Trying <private ip>...
* No route to host
* Failed connect to <private ip>:9009; No route to host
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to <private ip>:9009; No route to host
```

Can someone please tell me what is going wrong here ?

OS- Red Hat 7

Comment: 2 ec2 instances are the same VPC ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan. Yes they are in the same VPC.

Comment: did you stop `firewalld` on the server ?

Comment: are you talking about iptables ?

Comment: yes. what's the output `firewall-cmd --list-all`

Comment: I disabled the firewall and now it's up. So does it mean all ports are disabled by default ?  Post this as ans so that I can accept.  That was very helpful. Thanks.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Red Hat 7, `firewalld` is enabled by default. so, please disable `firewalld` on Red Hat 7

OR open port 9009 only as needed:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=9009/tcp

firewall-cmd --reload
```